# How much time takes to migrate from Magento CE to Magento EE?

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-community, migration

I have a Magento CE live site with some 10 modules and 15 third party modules and now I want to migrate to EE edition.

Can anyone tell me how much approx time it will takes and step of how to migrate to EE?

Comment: 1. Are you planning to do version upgrade as part of this migration?
2. Is this in M1 or M2?

Comment: I am using magento 1.8 CE version and I want to migrate in Magento 1.x in EE. Please suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Enterprise code base from your EE account.
2. Copy over your custom modules and themes to EE code base.
3. You have to review all phtml files under your theme and copy over changes from EE base/default themes.
4. If you have any 3rd party modules that do not compatible with EE you have to get the relevant EE module from the vendor.
5. Update etc/local.xml

You can find more details here. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_upgrade_ce18_upgrade-roadmap.html

-- Updated --
If you do not have lots of modules and files under theme it will take about 8-12 hours for the process.